# Lock a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a command/SQL query to lock a particular table in MS SQL Server to stop all related transactions using ODBC?

Answer (score 3):

Use the table hints, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

See [Table Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) in Books Online for more details.

Comment: The TABLOCK hint is used to request a shared lock. You will most likely want to use TABLOCKX in order to obtain an exclusive lock.